# Get youngest Person from List<Person> where Person has date of Birth in string ISO8601 fromat

Tags: java, datetime, java-stream

```
class Person {
    String name;
    String id;
    String dateOfBirth;
    int salary;
 }

 List <Person> listOfPersons; // Consider that list is filled with some data
```

e.g. `dateOfBirth = "2018-12-10T13:49:51.141Z";`

Date of birth is in ISO8601 and can be converted to `java.util.Date`
with `Date.from(Instant.parse(dateOfBirth));`
if that can help to sort the list.

So is there any way of using streams or nice solution in JAVA 8 to get the youngest Person from list of persons?

Additional comment: Person class can not be changed.

Comment: Make `Person` implement `Comparable`, compare the String to a `LocalDateTime` (avoid the old `java.util.Date`) and delegate the comparison so the `LocalDateTime` instances.

Comment: A birthdate really shouldnt be a `Date` object - this class is legacy, dont use it. It should be a `LocalDate` object instead. Or, if you actually want to capture the moment in time it happened, use an `Instant`. Tldr, learn your date/time-types.

Comment: Use a `LocalDate` here, it's the most suitable class because it only holds *date* values: day of month, month of year and year. Btw, your `dateOfBirth` even has a time zone / offset, which might have to be handled when parsing it to, let's say, a `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: I can not change Person class. Thing is that I have Date of birth in ISO8601, and I can not change that also. I put person class so you all understand easy what is bordering me.  So my problem is I need to get salary from the youngest Person.

Comment: [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)

Comment: @VanjaRadovanovic None of what you just said changes anything here. What we are saying is that you should not parse your `String dateOfBirth` as `Date` object. But as `LocalDate` or `Instant` instead. All of them can easily parse ISO-8601 compliant strings. And then you can sort on those. If the string truly looks like what you showed, i.e. with full time and zone info in it, and all you want is to sort it chronologically, I would go for `Instant.parse(dateOfBirth)`. For example `persons.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(person -> Instant.parse(dateOfBirth))).map(person -> person.salary);`.

Comment: Why should he even parse the date at all? The good thing about  ISO-8601 dates is that their alphabetic order is the same as their natural order. He can just sort on the String without doing any parsing.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS That is an interesting property, I was not aware either. Cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
record Person(String name, String id, String dateOfBirth,
                int salary) {}
        
List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
        new Person("Jim", "10", "2018-12-10T13:49:51.141Z",
                20),
        new Person("Mary", "11", "2018-12-15T13:49:51.141Z",
                20),
        new Person("Bob", "12", "2018-12-12T13:49:51.141Z",
                20)));
```

- use `maxBy` since the youngest person would be born futher away from the epoch.
- parse with an `Instant` of time. You cannot parse your given format example using `LocalDateTime`

```
Person youngest = list.stream().collect(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator
        .comparing(p -> Instant.parse(p.dateOfBirth)))).get();

System.out.println(youngest);
```

prints

```
Person[name=Mary, id=11, dateOfBirth=2018-12-15T13:49:51.141Z, salary=20]
```

Note that `maxBy` returns an `Optional`, therefore the `get()` call at the end. You may want to return the `Optional<Person>` and then extract the date based on success of the lookup.

Comment: Why do you use `stream().collect(Collectors.maxBy(...))` instead of `stream().max(...)`?

Comment: Just thought of this first.

Comment: @JasonC  BTW, imho your answer should have been the accepted one.  So +1.

Comment: "Just thought of this first" -- Ah ok. As good a reason as any! It was a legit question because I'm not very familiar with `Collectors`. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can do like this

```
Person youngestPerson = listOfPersons.stream()
.reduce((p1, p2) -> LocalDateTime.parse(p1.getStringDateofBirth()).isAfter(LocalDateTime.parse(p2.getStringDateofBirth()))?p1:p2)
.orElse(null)
```

Comment: plus 1 and btw you can also use `stream().max()` rather than `reduce()` (and `Comparator` has some handy utility functions too for building them up).

Comment: To properly parse the date you should change `LocalDateTime` to either `Instant` ,`ZonedDateTime`, or `OffsetDateTime`.

Answer (score 5):

UTC ISO-8601 date strings can be compared lexicographically. The most elegant Java 8 solution in my opinion would therefore be:

```
Person youngest = listOfPersons.stream()
    .max(Comparator.comparing(p -> p.dateOfBirth)).get();
```

If you don't trust the string comparison, or your timezones are all over the place, you can parse the date if you wish:

```
Person youngest = listOfPersons.stream()
    .max(Comparator.comparing(p -> LocalDateTime.parse(p.dateOfBirth, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)))
    .get();
```

[Or even](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72721584/616460):

```
Person youngest = listOfPersons.stream()
    .max(Comparator.comparing(p -> Instant.parse(p.dateOfBirth))).get();
```

Note that you should probably use `LocalDateTime` (or `Instant`) rather than `Date`, as Java 8 has moved away from the old date/time APIs ([a good rundown here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro)). You'll need to use the [`ISO_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME) formatter to handle the `Z` zone at the end if you're using `LocalDateTime`.

[Runnable example is here.](https://ideone.com/HNwcwM)

---

API of interest:

- [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) is Java 8's sort of ... iterable transformation interface supporting lots of handy methods and method chaining. All `Collection` objects have a [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) member for obtaining one.
- [`Stream.max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) returns the maximum value in a stream according to some `Comparator` that you specify (which could be a lambda function, or, as in the above case, just a `Comparator` object).

  - The return value is actually an [`Optional<Person>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) in this case (e.g. if the list was empty there might be no value), so `get()` gets the value, or you could just leave it as an `Optional` if you want, or you could use e.g. `orElse(null)` instead of `get()` if you'd rather it be null for an empty list.
- [`Comparator.comparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) is a handy little utility that constructs a `Comparator<T>` given a function that maps a `T` to a comparable value.

So in the above code:

- `p -> p.dateOfBirth` (or `p -> LocalDateTime.parse(p.dateOfBirth)`, your call) is a lambda function which maps a person to their birthdate.
- `Comparator.comparing(...)`, when given said key mapping function, returns a `Comparator` that compares the birth date of two persons, performing the appropriate comparison depending on whether you used the `String` or the `LocalDateTime` version.
- `max()` returns the object with the maximum date, i.e. the youngest person.
- `get()` just gets the `Person` out of the `Optional<Person>`.

---

Full example (linked to ideone above):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;

class Ideone {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        
        Person youngest;
        
        // you could do string comparison if you know the timezones are consistent:
        
        youngest = listOfPersons.stream()
            .max(Comparator.comparing(p -> p.dateOfBirth)).get();
        
        System.out.println("youngest is: " + youngest.name + " " + youngest.dateOfBirth);

        // or you could just parse the date, a safer option:
        
        youngest = listOfPersons.stream()
            .max(Comparator.comparing(p -> LocalDateTime.parse(p.dateOfBirth, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME))).get();
        
        System.out.println("youngest is: " + youngest.name + " " + youngest.dateOfBirth);
        
    }

    
    //------------------------------------
    // types from OP:
    
    static class Person{
        String name;
        String id;
        String dateOfBirth;
        int salary;
    }

    static List <Person> listOfPersons;

    
    //------------------------------------
    // boring example data initialization:
    
    // make an iso birthdate string given an age (for initializing data)
    static String fromAge (int years) {
        //return LocalDateTime.now().minusYears(years).toString();
        // add zone to emulate OP's input:
        return LocalDateTime.now().minusYears(years).toString() + 'Z';
    }
    
    // make up some data
    static {
        listOfPersons = List.of(
            // fine for example, but i wouldn't init like this in production
            new Person() {{ name="helga"; dateOfBirth=fromAge(22); }},
            new Person() {{ name="mortimer"; dateOfBirth=fromAge(48); }},
            new Person() {{ name="gertrude"; dateOfBirth=fromAge(6); }},
            new Person() {{ name="jebediah"; dateOfBirth=fromAge(39); }}
        );
        listOfPersons.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.name + ' ' + p.dateOfBirth));
    }

    
}
```

Outputs:

```
helga 2000-06-23T03:07:26.084850Z
mortimer 1974-06-23T03:07:26.126628Z
gertrude 2016-06-23T03:07:26.126894Z
jebediah 1983-06-23T03:07:26.127948Z
youngest is: gertrude 2016-06-23T03:07:26.126894Z
youngest is: gertrude 2016-06-23T03:07:26.126894Z
```

Comment: By "most elegant" I mean "most Java 8-y", heh.

Comment: You can't parse the OP's specified format (`"2018-12-10T13:49:51.141Z"`) using `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: @WJS You can if you use the `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME` formatter. Thanks for catching it though.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by others, use `LocalDateTime`. `LocalDateTime` has very conveniant functions, that fit exactly your problem. You can directly parse your String into it, just remove the "Z" from your ISO string and you're good:

```java
LocalDateTime someBirthday = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-12-10T13:49:51.141");
```

Next step, write a comparator:

```java
public class BirthdayComparator implements Comparator<LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public int compare(LocalDateTime date1, LocalDateTime date2) {
        if(date1.isAfter(date2)) {
            return 1;
        } else if (date1.equals(date2)) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Thats it. You can now sort for birth dates.

**Update**

One last word of caution: This code ignores time zones. To be precise, it implicitly assumes, all given birthdays are in the **same** time zone. This can be problematic, if you have to deal with persons all over the globe...

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is already `Comparable`. No need to write a Comparator for it :)

Comment: Ah OK, didn't know that. Well..., then just parse string.

Comment: You don't need to do a full sort; you can use `Stream.max()`. That way you won't modify the original list and also, performance wise, it's just a linear search for a maximum rather than a complete sort.